# should I restart Rails App? if I want to use enum from db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to use enum for select options, and values are from DB.
just like below.
key is "id", value is "name"

COUNTRY = Country.select("name", "id").map {|item| [item.name.to_sym, item.id] }.to_h
  enum country_id: COUNTRY
  def country_id_enum
    COUNTRY
  end

but after I create, create update delete mothods, I realized data will not be applied if I dont restart rails app.(service httpd restart)

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should write method accessor, not the constant

```
class Dictionaries
  def countries
    #load and return what you need here.
  end
end
```

Comment: can you give me more examples please?